# 'System.NotSupportedException' in PresentationCore.dll appeared in Output panel

Tags: c#, wpf, exception, visual-studio-2015

I've built a C# WPF application that can monitor print jobs. Everything works fine. I can print a document and monitor its print job.

But every time I click the "Print Form" button, which triggers the "on print job change" event, I get a message `Exception thrown: 'System.NotSupportedException' in PresentationCore.dll` three times in the Output panel (See more message below). At first I think that it comes from console logging codes like `Console.Write` or `Console.WriteLine`, but when I check for them, my program doesn't have any.

So I checked on what is that System.NotSupportedException [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.notsupportedexception(v=vs.110).aspx).

I see that

> The exception that is thrown when an invoked method is not supported, or when there is an attempt to read, seek, or write to a stream that does not support the invoked functionality.

And then I recall that in my "on print job change" event handler, I have some statements that invoke objects from different thread (I don't know what the term is). Then I tried to disable every line that has invocation. But when the application is run again, the message is still there.

Here is the full message in the Output panel that comes from the first click of "Print Form" button (at the second click and after, it's not showing the first line and the last two lines):

```
'PrintClientWPF.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: PrintClientWPF.vshost.exe): Loaded 'Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly'. 
Exception thrown: 'System.NotSupportedException' in PresentationCore.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.NotSupportedException' in PresentationCore.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.NotSupportedException' in PresentationCore.dll
The thread 0x1f18 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x272c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Here is my event handler of "on print job change" event:

```cs
public async void PrintHelperInstance_PrintJobsChange(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
{
    ManagementBaseObject objProps = (ManagementBaseObject)e.NewEvent.Properties["TargetInstance"].Value;

    string instanceOperation = e.NewEvent.SystemProperties["__Class"].Value.ToString();
    string jobName = objProps["Document"].ToString();

    if (JobNameList.Contains(jobName))
    {
        if (!IsFoundPrintJob)
        {
            IsFoundPrintJob = true;
        }

        CurrentJobStatus = (string)objProps["JobStatus"];

        if (CurrentJobStatus != PreviousJobStatus)
        {
            uint jobId = (uint)objProps["JobId"];
            string jobDriver = (string)objProps["DriverName"];
            string jobHost = (string)objProps["HostPrintQueue"];
            string jobStatus = (string)objProps["JobStatus"];

            // Use Dispatcher.Invoke to execute statements from a thread other than the main thread
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                string printerName = PrintHelperInstance.GetPrintQueueFromQueueDriverName(jobDriver).Name;
                string msg = string.Format("ID: {0}, Name: {1}, Printed on: {2}, Host: {3}, Status: {4}",
                    jobId, jobName, printerName, jobHost, jobStatus);

                TextBlockPrintJobStatus.Text += msg + System.Environment.NewLine;
            });

            PreviousJobStatus = CurrentJobStatus;
        }
    }

    // Indicates that the print job has been deleted
    if (IsFoundPrintJob && instanceOperation == "__InstanceDeletionEvent")
    {
        this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            TextBlockPrintJobStatus.Text += "Print completed" + System.Environment.NewLine;
        });

        IsFoundPrintJob = false;

        string postResponse = "";

        try
        {
            // TODO: Not implemented yet, just testing here
            postResponse = await ApiHelperInstance.Post(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("id", "1"));
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException ex)
        {
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                TextBlockPrintJobStatus.Text += "HTTP Request Error: " + ex.Message + System.Environment.NewLine;
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                TextBlockPrintJobStatus.Text += "Exception: " + ex.Message + System.Environment.NewLine;
            });
        }
        finally
        {
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                TextBlockPrintJobStatus.Text += postResponse + System.Environment.NewLine;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Actually I'm new at C# and I don't have advanced knowledge of anything like this.

So my question is, **why is that exception message appeared** and **how can I get rid of it?**

Comment: Seeing the debugger display these "first chance" exception notifications is pretty normal in a WPF app, especially so when printing.  PresentationCore has lots of try/catch code.  There is no indication whatsoever in your question that this caused a real problem.  At least document it better, use Debug > Windows > Exception Settings, tick the "Common Language Runtime Exceptions" checkbox and post the content of the Call Stack debugger window when the exception hits.

Comment: @HansPassant It seems that I don't have to look at the Call Stack debugger because after I tick that option in Exception Settings, the same exception is thrown with additional information `BitmapMetadata is not available on BitmapImage`. Apparently it comes from `BitmapImage` inside my `FixedDocument` which is the object that the application printed. What should I do? Can I really get rid of the exception?